# Wordpress job listing auto published indeed site

Tags: wordpress

I am a new WordPress developer, I have a client that would like their job posting to automatically published on indeed.

I was looking for information on the best way to proceed.

Please help me, can anyone guide in the right direction?

Comment: http://opensource.indeedeng.io/api-documentation/

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

You need to send them an XML feed of your jobs, brah.

Please read thier full documentation: https://www.indeed.co.uk/intl/en/xmlinfo.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<source>
<publisher>Example Job Site</publisher>
<publisherurl>http://www.examplejobsite.com</publisherurl>
<lastBuildDate>Fri, 10 Dec 2008 22:49:39 GMT</lastBuildDate>
<job>
<title><![CDATA[Sales Executive]]></title>
<date><![CDATA[Fri, 10 Dec 2005 22:49:39 GMT]]></date>
<referencenumber><![CDATA[unique123131]]></referencenumber>
<url><![CDATA[http://www.examplejobsite.com/viewjob.cfm?jobid=unique123131]]></url>
<company><![CDATA[Big ABC Corporation]]></company>
<city><![CDATA[Phoenix]]></city>
<state><![CDATA[AZ]]></state>
<country><![CDATA[US]]></country>
<postalcode><![CDATA[85003]]></postalcode>
<description><![CDATA[Do you have 1-3 years of sales experience? Are you relentless at closing the deal? Are you ready for an exciting and high-speed career in sales? If so, we want to hear from you!

[...]

We provide competitive compensation, including stock options and a full benefit plan. As a fast-growing business, we offer excellent opportunities for exciting and challenging work. As our company continues to grow, you can expect unlimited career advancement! ]]></description>
<salary><![CDATA[$50K per year]]></salary>
<education><![CDATA[Bachelors]]></education>
<jobtype><![CDATA[fulltime, parttime]]></jobtype>
<category><![CDATA[Category1, Category2, CategoryN]]></category>
<experience><![CDATA[5+ years]]></experience>
</job>
[...]
</source>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Creating Auto Update / Auto Publish sites checklist are:

1. Install WP Automatic Plugin
2. Find RSS Feed of the site, which you want to fetch post/jobs (It is necessary to site allow to fetch post via RSS)
3. Configure Plugin
4. Set the interval time limit (For checking again to fetch new post/jobs)
5. Assign the specific category to specific post /jobs
6. Done!

If you face any further problem, feel free to ask me.